# Is it possible to redirect squid traffic from Host A through Host B(Squid)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy, squid

Can traffic of Host A having squid proxy redirect all its traffic to Host B's squid proxy using ssh tunnel? Couldn't find any solution. A help will be appreciated.

Solution form this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490641/587328 helps to sent all http and https traffic thought Host B but squid traffic still pass through Host A.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think it can help you:

In host A write this:

```shell
ssh -p 3567 -f -N -L *:4445:localhost:3567 <username>@<server B>
```

in this code all traffic in port 4445 in server A forward to server B port 3567.